# How do you pronounce the name Keqing?

Tags: pronunciation

In a video game, there is a female character named Keqing. You can read up about her [here](https://genshin.gg/characters/Keqing), although for the purposes of this question I assume her name alone is all that matters. This game was developed by a Chinese company, I'm not sure if this matters (i.e. perhaps her name was influenced by that fact and may be helpful).

What is the proper way to pronounce her name?

Comment: The closest English pronunciation is /kʊ tʃi:ŋ/, where /ʊ/ rhymes with the vowel in 'look', and the stress on both syllables equally.

Comment: You cannot deduce the pronunciation of a name from its spelling. I know three different people named *Andrea* and each pronounces it differently from the other two. For a fictional character, there will be either a creator or a fandom to provide opinions.

Comment: @choster: for a spelling in Pinyin, you can do a pretty good job, and Mitch has explained the best English pronunciation. (Although I believe the stress actually depends on the tones, which you can't deduce from the Pinyin.)

Comment: [This post on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Genshin_Impact/comments/j4e0a1/how_to_pronounce_all_the_chinese_gi_characters/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share) says that the q is pronounced like "t's".

Comment: @Mitch - I immediately said 'kee-king' to myself. Like Peking.

Comment: I think most native English speakers would pronounce it poorly and hesitantly.

Comment: No doubt that will change in the future.

Comment: @PeterShor It would be very awful sounding to pronounce it 'ka CHING'. Calling it a spondee is just avoiding that. Mandarin words tend to be trochaic, but a two syllable name is more like a spondee.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about Chinese pronunciation rather than English usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an English name, but a Chinese one, which is a transliteration of Chinese characters/pictographs (克清). (So this is probably not the domain of this Stack Exchange site since this is literally an English language website, but I will try to answer)

From researching the name **Keqing**, and looking for information on Chinese characters named similarly, I hit upon [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kang_Keqing) about a person named **Kang Keqing** and assume it is pronounced the same.

The pronunciation is described as: K'e-ching (Kèqīng) so I assume something like: Koo-cheeng

Google translate describes the name as:

**Keqing**, pronounced kè qīng, is a Chinese word meaning to conquer and calm down

The Google Translate link is [here](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-CN&u=https://baike.baidu.com/item/%25E5%2585%258B%25E6%25B8%2585&prev=search&pto=aue).
Hope this helps.

Comment: The pronunciation of 'ke' (regardless of the falling tone) is, to my mind, most closely represented in English by "cuh" which is a bit ĺike 'uh'  with a hard 'c' in front of it and 'qing'  (regardless of the high tone) is more like 'ching' than anything else so I would say that 'keqing' sounds like "cuhching'. Unfortunately that's awfully close to  "ker-ching" but that's what can happen when words move from one language to another. Adding the falling tone to 'ke'  and the high tone to 'ching' improves things but that requires knowledge of the tones and the Pin Yin tone marks.

Comment: Very useful info, thanks Ben. I listened to the Google translate "speak" feature, and transcribed as best as I could, however your transcription seems closer to what was spoken than mine, so thanks for that. I provided the link above, so take a listen and see if you agree with the google translate pronunciation (which is often inaccurate)